# monkey patching time.time() in python

Tags: python, ruby, datetime, time, monkeypatching

I've an application where, for testing, I need to replace the time.time() call with a specific timestamp, I've done that in the past using ruby

(code available here: http://github.com/zemariamm/Back-to-Future/blob/master/back_to_future.rb )

However I do not know how to do this using Python.

Any hints ?
Cheers,
Ze Maria

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply set time.time to point to your new time function, like this:

```
import time

def my_time():
    return 0.0

old_time = time.time
time.time = my_time
```